# Could not find property 'VERSION_CODE' Error:(21,0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import a project in my Android Studio 1.5.1. I firstly removed one error of 'com.android.application' not found but then this error has been risen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi8pP.png)

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find property 'VERSION_CODE' on
>   ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null,
>   minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=14, mCodename='null'},
>   targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=23, mCodename='null'},
>   renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null,
>   applicationId=com.fractalwrench.androidbootstrap.sample,
>   testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null,
>   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null,
>   testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null,
>   mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[],
>   mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

Comment: How did you define the VERSION_CODE variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the VERSION_CODE and VERSION_NAME. I guess they are missing in your project. You can hardcode the version code and version name  like this -

```
versionCode 21
versionName "1.0"
```

or can make it dynamic like this -

```
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 1
def versionBuild = 0
defaultConfig {
  versionCode versionMajor * 1000000 + versionMinor * 10000 + versionBuild * 100
  versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionBuild}"
}
```